# Make part of an url disappear using php, or another language

Tags: php, url, hide

this is something i've looked for but not found 
i'd like to make the url on my website show only a part of the itself, and showing the full url only when clicking on it (as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwGw3.png))

if possible i'd like to do it in php, but if that's not possible i'd like to know what language to use and how to do it

Thanks!

Comment: You can't change how browsers show URL's. That's part of the browsers UI, not your application.

Comment: There is an option to use a database system and an ID for each URL. Then to activate an AJAX when the user clicks on the short URL. That AJAX will get a full URL from a database, and then in JS, you can redirect the user, and show the full URL to him.

Comment: @NemanjaJeremic - As far as I understand, that's not really what they are asking for. They want to keep the short URL in the addressbar but show the long URL when they click on the addressbar.

Comment: I don't think this can be done, unless you redirect to the omitted part of URL which is a masked version of the original URL.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, yeah you are right, it is not possible to change the URL preview. But it can be tricked with JS and with some sort of the database.

Comment: @NemanjaJeremic - But you won't be able to solve _"and showing the full url only when clicking on it"_ since, as far as I know, you can't get a "click"-event from the address bar.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - Yeah, that's right. The only solution as I think it so, is to follow the user mouse pointer and to make an event when user pointer crosses the upper border of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The behavior how urls are being displayed in browsers is not up to the server, only the browser can do that. If it's just for yourself you could modify your browser I suppose.